# Counting number of instances inside a struct in swift

Tags: swift, struct, count, instances

I'm very new to Swift and I can't figure this one out. I need to count the number of instances created inside a struct. Since I created 3 instances, how can I get the program to tell me there are three? I tried the exNames.count at the end, but that doesn't work... Thanks!

```
struct People {
    let name: String
    var age: Int
    let sex: Character
}

var heather = People(name: "Heather", age: 32, sex: "F")
var peter = People(name: "Peter", age: 34, sex: "M")
var scott = People(name: "Scott", age: 27, sex: "M")

let exNames = [People]()

exNames.count
```

Comment: `exNames` is an empty array. – Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38021844/count-number-of-instances-of-a-class-swift.

Comment: I'm not even sure how to ask the question properly, but how would I count the number of People who have sex=M

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a static variable on the `People` struct. However, this does require overriding the default initializer.

```
struct People
{
    static var instances = 0

    let name:String
    var age:Int
    let sex:Character

    init(name:String, age:Int, sex:Character)
    {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.sex = sex

        People.instances += 1
    }
}

var heather = People(name: "Heather", age: 32, sex: "F")
var peter = People(name: "Peter", age: 34, sex: "M")
var scott = People(name: "Scott", age: 27, sex: "M")

let exNames = [People]() 
/* exNames.count only gives the number of People that are 
contained in this particular array, which is zero. */

print(People.instances) // 3
```

If you want to *decrement* the count when the `struct`s go out of scope, you need to upgrade to a `class` which provides a deinitializer `deinit {}`.

Note that the “proper” use cases for a static counter are exceedingly limited. It is very likely that the problem you are actually trying to solve would be better served by a different hammer.

By the way, you really shouldn’t be using `Character` to represent `sex`, as `Character` in Swift is very closely tied to strings, and so they are built and optimized for lexical purposes, not for flagging. It also opens the door for a lot of potential bugs, as Swift won’t be able to verify valid input as well (what if someone accidentally passes a `sex` value of `"@"`?) Instead, use the built in `Bool` type, or a custom `enum` if you need more functionality.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you wanted to create an array of people, in that case:

```
struct People {
    let name: String
    var age: Int
    let sex: Character
}

var heather = People(name: "Heather", age: 32, sex: "F")
var peter = People(name: "Peter", age: 34, sex: "M")
var scott = People(name: "Scott", age: 27, sex: "M")

//This should be a var, because you are going to modify it
var exNames = [People]()

exNames.append(heather)
exNames.append(peter)
exNames.append(scott)

exNames.count
```